# Was that a shooting star or a spaceship?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, millennium-falcon

In the final scene from *The Last Jedi*, we see a boy, Temiri Blagg (aka "Broom Boy") look up into the starry night sky. He witnesses a streak of light occur high in the heavens, but I always thought this was simply a shooting star.

However, I was reading a [review of the film's soundtrack](http://www.filmtracks.com/titles/last_jedi.html) when the writer stated:

> One of the children (...) looks up to see the Millennium Falcon go to light speed

Which leads me to wonder, **do we know for sure what that was?**
 Was it a shooting star? The Millennium Falcon? Some other ship? etc.

---

Video footage of the scene in question (best quality I could find):

Comment: Nice music and promotional tie-in, I can't say I wouldn't do it if I had the video and music cut.   I guess it is a ship going to lightspeed.

Comment: It was Hope :-p

Comment: @shreedhar a new hope?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a bird? Or a plane?

Comment: we do not know what ship it was, but it was clearly a ship. at 1:04 the bright light is semi-stationary and then a second later shoots off. While we do not know if it is the Falcon, we do know it is a ship. Nice catch, I thought it was a shooting star the first time I saw it as well.

Answer (score 4):

### It was a ship

We can tell this because it follows the pattern of slow acceleration followed by snapping off quickly. If it was a shooting star, it would have been a consistent speed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 - I agree, we do not know what ship it was, but it was clearly a ship. at 1:04 the bright light is semi-stationary and then a second later shoots off. While we do not know if it is the Falcon, we do know it is a ship.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, there's no canon confirmation ***yet*** (however, color me unsurprised if this idea is indeed confirmed in the novelization due out in March).

I tried to search for an answer in interviews, but it has seemingly not yet been addressed.

---

However, the idea does make sense insofar as Episode VII had similar imagery and symbolism (e.g., Kylo Ren watching the Starkiller ray passing by; then people at Maz's seeing the resulting explosion; you should probably also count Forceback where Rey sees what seems her parents' ship flying away from Jakku).

Comment: I've re-read your answer but I still don't understand what you're trying to say. I think there may be a few words missing or something, especially in the 2nd half. Ex: "the idea does make sense" what idea? etc.

Comment: @RedCaio - the idea that it was Millenium Falcon. We can't prove it but it does make sense, being inline with existing prior artistic approaches